# Pandas: apply background and font style in one go

Tags: python, pandas

Sounds *simples*, but I cannot find the correct way to do it.

my function below, applies only the style for background or for font, and I cannot find way to apply both...

Please advise how to apply in one go `'font-weight: bold' and 'background-color: #e5e5e5'`:

```
def color(df_):
    # Color rows grey and make text bold  where "Subtotal" is present
    styles_df = pd.DataFrame('', index=df_.index, columns=df_.columns)
    styles_df.loc[df_.PIN == 'Subtotal', :] = 'font-weight: bold'
    styles_df.loc[df_.PIN == 'Subtotal', :] = 'background-color: #e5e5e5'
    return styles_df
```

I have tried different options of the syntax without any luck (just few below) :)

```
styles_df.loc[df_.PIN == 'Subtotal', :] = (** {'font-weight: bold', 'background-color: #e5e5e5'})
```

or simple

```
styles_df.loc[df_.PIN == 'Subtotal', :] = 'font-weight: bold' and  'background-color: #e5e5e5'
```

Does not seem to work.

**Update and Solution:**
based on [@Quang Hoang](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4238408/quang-hoang) example I ended up with the code below.
the string should look like that `['background-color: #e5e5e5; font-weight: bold']`:

```
def color(df_):
    # Color rows yellow where there are any 0 values across rows - for Adjustment sheet
    styles_df = pd.DataFrame('', index=df_.index, columns=df_.columns)
    styles_df.loc[df_.Hours == 0, :] = 'background-color: yellow'
    styles_df.loc[df_.PIN == 'Subtotal', :] = ['background-color: #e5e5e5; font-weight: bold']
    return styles_df
```

later saving to excel:

```
with pd.ExcelWriter(FilePath) as writer:
        df_subtotals.style.apply(color, axis=None).to_excel(writer, index=False, sheet_name='Site Adjustments')
        df_timesheet.style.apply(colorTS, axis=None).to_excel(writer, index=False, sheet_name=proj_num)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can apply function on the rows like this:

```
def color(row):
    if row['a'] == 1: 
        return ['font-weight: bold; background-color: green'] * len(row)

data.style.apply(color, axis=1)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: thanks for the example, but now I cannot find the way to save yours to excel, - mine at least does

Comment: What do you mean? `df.style.apply().to_excel("file.xlsx")`

Comment: thanks mate, it seems another part of your code was very handy :)
I have updated my question